# How to compile the cross-compiler arm-linux-eabi-gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm

I am learning devolepment of embeded,based on arm architecture.My OS is ArchLinux,i have search cross-compilers package using pacman,but all i found is only arm-none-eabi-gcc. so i want to know where can i get the sources of arm-linux-eabi-gcc and how to complier it on my ArchLinux.Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download and install the free and prebuilt Codesourcery/Mentor Arm cross-compiler and toolchain from [here](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/).

Comment: My curiosity cacth me... i still want to know where to get the sources and how to compile them T^T